# Copy assets from NPM

Tags: node.js, fonts, npm, font-awesome

I'm trying to use [font-awesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) with npm but with the newest version (>4) I'm having difficulty finding the `fonts` directory.

Before, I was using a npm script like `cp -R ./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/assets/` but this doesn't work anymore when my library is used by a program that will regroup all the modules at the root directory.

Is there a safe method to know where they are or any other trick that could achieve the same goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: I implemented an npm utility to output node_module's path
https://github.com/lexoyo/node_modules-path

It just registers as a ".bin" script to be accessible in npm scripts, and the output is `Path.resolve(__dirname, '..');`.

So you can use this in your package.json or shell scripts:

```
$ mkdir -p dist/fonts
$ cp -R `node_modules`/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/fonts/"
```

The script exports the `NODE_MODULES` env var so you should be able to use it like this, but I did not test it:

```
$ mkdir -p dist/fonts
$ node_modules
$ cp -R ${NODE_MODULES}/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/fonts/"
```